# Visualize R program user input questions?

Tags: r, user-interface, interactive

In my `R` program the user has to type in some inputs. I did this with

```
readline('Please give the numerical input')
```

Depending on the input, the program computes further things.
My question, is it also possible to visualize the users questions a bit?
With readline everything happens in the console. Can I bring it in a nice format to the plot window (for example with a box where user can type in the input and than the program goes on depending on the input)?

Comment: If I understand the question, you would like some sort of a GUI for your program. This can be done using e.g. RGtk2 http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v037i08/v37i08.pdf

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for the link I will look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to consider two alternatives.

## svDialogs

Package `svDigalogs` would enable you to create an input window realitvly quickly. The code:

```
require(svDialogs)
## Ask something...
user <- dlgInput("Who are you?", Sys.info()["user"])$res
if (!length(user)) { # The user clicked the 'cancel' button
  cat("OK, you prefer to stay anonymous!\n")
} else {
  cat("Hello", user, "\n")
}
```

would generate the following window:

[image: Input window]

## Shiny

Not sure if you considered that but you could quickly put together a [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) with console and some input field. You could build a [dynamic UI](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) element asking user for input, if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to read more in detail about your and Roman's suggestions (it is new for me-especially Shiny). But this was exactely what I was looking for

Comment: @fabian92 No problem, glad to read that the answer is of some use to you. Presumably, the choice of solution depends on how you want to share your product, `svDialogs` solution will be very easy to implement but it will work if end-users have no problem with running your code themselves and provide you with most basic UI functionalities. Shiny and RGtk2 may be more time consuming to implement but would provide greater flexibility.